# How to zero-fill charts/bins in Application Insights Analytics

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

I'm trying to plot an area chart of one sum/count metric over time in Application Insights:

```
customEvents
| where timestamp > ago(7d)
| summarize count() by bin(timestamp, 1h)
| render areachart
```

What I see is that if there is no data in some buckets then chart doesn't drop to 0. Instead two dots are connected and there is perception that there were some data when in fact there were not.

Question - how to get zero-filled area charts (corresponding to red ink chart)?

[image]

Answer (score 26, accepted):

There are several ways to achieve this.

[make-series](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/make-seriesoperator) operator allows to set default value for the periods where no data is present for aggregation:

```
customEvents
| where timestamp > ago(10m)
| make-series count() default=0 on timestamp in range(ago(10m), now(), 1m)
| render areachart
```

This will produce zero-filled data array and `| render` will build the chart accordingly.

If `| summarize` is preferred, you can create zero-filled range yourself with [range](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/rangeoperator) operator:

```
let defaultValue = 0;
range timestamp from floor(ago(10m),1m) to floor(now() + 10m,1m) step 1m
| join kind=leftouter
(
    customEvents
    | where timestamp > floor(ago(10m),1m) and timestamp < floor(now(),1m)
    | summarize Value=count() by bin(timestamp, 1m)
) on timestamp
| project timestamp, value = iff(isnotempty(Value), Value, defaultValue)
| render areachart
```

Make sure to use `join kind=leftouter` to have all timestamps from the left side of the join present in output.

Comment: make-series produces one row of weird arrays in Kusto explorer, rather than normal rows.

Comment: Yes, I think that's the intent of make-series to allow for [in-depth series analysis](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/make-seriesoperator#list-of-series-analysis-functions) if required.

Comment: It's nice to understand the motivation for make-series, but still neither of these are good solutions to the problem: make-series doesn't produce rows, and range requires restructuring and complicating the query. What we need is a simple modifier to bin that ensures that there is a row for every bin, whether it contains any events or not.

Comment: I'd expect a built-in way to do it without changing the query logic.
for example `| render areachart with zero-fill`